# How to give initial data to put method ,Django (I want to create edit profile page)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this Put function :

```
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Http404

def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
            user = self.get_object(pk)
            serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.errors,satus=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

here when you want to edit a user, you need to type the field you want to change and new value for it. But the problem is here that username and password are required field and even if you do not want to change them you need to type them. I want there be a way that I can define (inside my code) that in username and password fields automatically current user and password fill and if user want to change them type his new value.

Comment: Perhaps a direct approach rather than drf will be better

Comment: the existing views already have a get_object and put similar to what you have so there's really no use reimplementing them. And then again, what is your question exactly? how to implement it on the frontend?

Comment: @Ken4scholars may you please check my update?

Comment: @Annabelle then you can use a PATCH request instead

Comment: @Annabelle check out my answer and don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to use the existing put method and get_object in DRF's API views and viewsets as they're quite similar to what you have.

As for your question, the backend already has everything you need, so what you need to do is this:

1. Send a get request to fetch the user object
2. Display the values on a form and allow the user to edit the fields he wants
3. Send back the new values including old ones that were not edited to the backend using a put request
4. The view seralizes them, validates and updates the user object

That's really all you need and as you can see, the backend already has all that is needed.

Bear in mind however, that password fields shouldn't be edited in the same way like the rest as they need to be hashed before saving. It is a common practice to have separate change password page where you can handle password updated the correct way.
However, if you still want to update the password the same way as the rest, then you can do something like this in your serializer:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    if password:
        instance.set_password(password)
    return instance
```

**FOR PARTIAL UPDATE**

If you want to be able to send only the fields changed to the backend, then use the PATCH HTTTP method which is used for *partial updates* in REST terminology. It has already been implemented by DRF to allow missing values for required fields so you don't have to implement it yourself